# Disable video loop

Tags: firefox, video, browser-addons, css

Some sites are using the `loop` attribute with video

```htm
<video loop="loop"></video>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtZW9.jpg)

I do not like this. I would prefer the video to play once, then give me the
option to repeat like YouTube. I am currently using Firefox and I have the
Stylish add-on, but I am not sure if the loop can be disabled purely with CSS.

If this cannot be done with CSS/Stylish, can it be done with another add-on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Firefox

1. Install [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/scriptish/) (I couldn't get it to work with Greasemonkey for some reason)
2. Restart Firefox
3. Install [this userscript](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2670f45bf656479c8d91) by clicking on [this link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2670f45bf656479c8d91/raw/ac742d6a4edb74b75d56c3d1e564c04e4ccfe1e5/prevent-gif-looping.user.js)
4. Reload Imgur.com

### Google Chrome

1. Install [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija/) or a similar addon
2. Visit **imgur.com** or whichever website you wish to disable video looping for
3. Click on the blue button in the toolbar that says **cjs** and add the following JS code:

   ```
   document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("loop");
   ```
4. Save the script and reload Imgur.com

### To toggle looping [using a keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511474/1768141), use this:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @id imgur.com@scriptish
// @name prevent-gif-looping
// @version 1.1
// @namespace imgur.com
// @author Vinayak
// @description Block GIFs from looping on Imgur
// @include http*://imgur.com/*
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
function stopLooping(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("loop");
    loop=false;
}

function startLooping(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].setAttribute("loop", "loop");
    document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].load();
    loop=true;
}

function doc_keyUp(e) {
    // B = key code 66. Press B to toggle looping
    if (e.keyCode == 66) {
        if(loop) { stopLooping(); } else { startLooping(); }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("loop");
var loop=false;
```

The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>B</kbd>. Press that to toggle video looping. To use this script with Google Chrome, copy the code and paste it into the extension as instructed above.

To use it with Firefox, use [this link](https://gist.github.com/1oh1/d16f71c928490c37fd6b/raw/0a161b192fe45b9b7ca4c76bc29f6c730b41bd05/prevent-gif-looping.user.js) to install the userscript in the steps mentioned above.

---

Notes: I'm not sure this can be achieved just by using CSS. Maybe it's possible by some creative use of the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property?

Userscript sourcecode:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @id imgur.com@scriptish
// @name prevent-gif-looping
// @version 1.0
// @namespace imgur.com
// @author Vinayak
// @description Block GIFs from looping on Imgur
// @include http*://imgur.com/*
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].removeAttribute("loop");
```